# Running method in another class works... half way?

Tags: iphone

```
//AppDelegate (In applicationDidEnterForeground)
SomeClass* object = [[SomeClass alloc]init];
[object SomeMethod:nil];

//In SomeClass.h
-(void)SomeMethod:(id)sender;

//In SomeClass.m
-(void)SomeMethod:(id)sender {
    SomeUILabel.text = @"hehehe!!";
}
```

I planted a breakpoint on SomeUILabel.text line and it went through. But SomeUILabel.text did not change. Can you tell me what's missing?

Comment: Where is your SomeUILabel defined ?

Comment: are you working on the mainthread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `SomeClass` is a view controller?  You shouldn't really be trying to control the view controller in this way, it's the view controller's job to manage its views.

One thing you have to remember is that the main view of a view controller is lazily loaded.  If you have a nib file where you set up `SomeUILabel`, then it's going to be `nil` until that nib is loaded.  That nib isn't going to be loaded until UIKit thinks that the view is needed.  An extremely hacky way of testing if this is the problem is to `NSLog(@"%@", object.view);` before sending the `SomeMethod:` message.  This will trigger the loading of the view, so as long as `SomeUILabel` is a correctly hooked up `IBOutlet`, this will then work.  But you really need to reorganise your code, that's the real problem here.

Comment: SomeUILabel is null. How do I trigger the loading of the view? NSLog("%@", object.view); returned an error (Passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' from incompatible pointer type)

Comment: Oops, my mistake: NSLog(@"%@", object.view);

Comment: The `NSLog` call is enough to trigger the loading of the view.  It's a hack though, you shouldn't ever use it for anything other than a quick debugging test.  You could also call `[object loadView];`.

Comment: All I need is SomeUILabel to display a certain text when application enters foreground. What's a better way to reorganise the code?

Comment: I'd post a notification and let any view controllers that are interested in the foreground state listen for it.

Comment: Hmm [object loadView]; doesn't make it work. How do I post such notifications?

Comment: Did you check you've got the `IBOutlet` hooked up properly?

Comment: [Notification Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i)

Comment: yes, its hooked up properly. I tried calling it from the view controller, it's fine. Sheesh, I'll give that notification thing a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Jim!!! I'm done setting up notifications. it's working now :D sounded difficult but easier than it seems! hehehe

Answer (score 1):

try NSLog(@"hehehe!!")
I suppose it will work

I think you are calling the method while "SomeUILabel" is still nil

May be you haven't created the label, or if you are loading a xib file, you are calling the method before this xib is loaded.

Comment: SomeUILabel is defined within SomeClass. I called SomeMethod with [self SomeMethod:nil]; from within SomeClass, it works. When I called SomeMethod from the AppDelegate, this happens.

Comment: add 
NSLog(@"%@,"SomeUILabel); in your  SomeMethod.
   
is someUILabel nil ?